# Error 438 when opening a workbook with variables

Tags: excel, vba, syntax-error

I am still learning VBA, but I know this is most likely a simple mistake, and I would like some help getting through this errored code. The variable "isum" that I created to replace a workbook that daily changes its name is getting an error 438. I cannot open it using 'filepath & wb' because of the '&' so I made a variable for them both. I am trying to copy a section on a sheet from one workbook, pasting to another sheet area on a different workbook. Here is my code:

```
    Sub Summary()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'create variables
Dim wb As String
Dim filepath As String
Dim isum As Workbook
Dim CBD As Workbook

'variables for file with changing date in name title
filepath = "\\main\stuff\Summary\"
wb = "Today Summary " & Format(Date, "m.dd") - 0.01 & ".xlsb"

'open both
Set isum = Workbooks.Open(filepath & wb)
Set CBD = Workbooks.Open("\\main\other\CBD forecast.xlsx")

'copy
CBD.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B3:J3000").Copy
'Now, transfer values from x to y:
isum.Sheets("Sheet7").Range("A2").Paste 'error 438, it copies but does not paste

'Close x:
CBD.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is Summary a folder or the first part of the workbook name? If the former, you are missing a backslash between the host folder and the workbook name.

Comment: My apologies,I just edited to correct it. It was previously there, I just accidentally erased the slash when I copied and pasted the code into this question. So, the problem still arises.

Comment: `wb = "Today Summary " & Format(Date, "m.dd") & " - 0.01.xlsb"` might be closer to the truth. If not, please disclose **exactly** what you are trying to concatenate the string into.
`

Comment: No, but thank you. The string 'wb' is supposed to be a file name that changes daily based on the date (i.e. Today Summary 6.20, Today Summary 6.21, Today Summary 6.22, and so forth). I want to open this file to paste on, but it will not let me paste the 'filepath & wb' because of the '&' symbol, so I made isum = filepath & wb. The "- .01" is opening the file name from the date before the current date to reassess. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, the wb (workbook) string should be linked into the exact `filepath` above, and should be in the `wb` file as "Today Summary 6.29" for Friday's date. So the `Today Summary 6.28` workbook will be under the file "Summary" under that filepath. I hope I am answering your question.

Comment: OK, so you are looking for `Today Summary 6.29.xlsb` within the Summary **folder**. I'll write a string format/concatenation below that should work.

Comment: Thank you, a side note is that I understand the `- .01` will not work as a new month is restarting because it will give an off date, but I just wanted to start this first so I do not involve another thread in this thread. If that happens to help.

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>the wb file as "Today Summary 6.29" for Friday's date.</sub>

```
wb = "Today Summary " & Format(Date, "m.dd") - 0.01 & ".xlsb"
```

You seem to be concatenating some part of a test string into the desired workbook name.

```
'variables for file with changing date in name title
filepath = "\\main\stuff\Summary\"
wb = "Today Summary " & Format(Date, "m.dd") & ".xlsb"
```

Also recommended, use the Destination parameter of a Copy operation when pasting to a single target.

```
CBD.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B3:J3000").Copy _
   destination:=isum.Sheets("Sheet7").Range("A2")
```

Comment: So, this is accurate, the workbooks are opening, the CBD sheet is copied; however, the `isum` (for the filepath and wb) is not activating the sheet7 to paste on. This is where the error 438 lies.

Comment: Try this all in one line like `CBD.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B3:J3000").Copy destination:=isum.Sheets("Sheet7").Range("A2")` .

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. A brief reason of why the previous way did not work would be much appreciated.

Comment: Regrettably, I don't work with the clipboard much anymore and prefer using the Destination:= parameter when I do so I really have no succinct response for you. Perhaps if someone with relevant experience comes by this thread they could add one.